# Is stopping the azure stream analytics will stop the costing?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-databricks

I would need to know that,
Is stopping Azure stream analytics service will stop the costing.

Comment: Hi, it's nice to mark the post as answer if it's helpful, you can follow this [article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d446ee4-ef3a-4a2b-be6b-c5c9ae5809b4/stream-analytics-price?forum=AzureStreamAnalytics) from MSFT: For Azure Stream Analytics, there is no charge when the job is stopped.

But for [Azure Stream Analytics on IoT Edge](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/stream-analytics/): Billing starts when an ASA job is deployed to devices, no matter what the job status is (running/failed/stopped).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

**Note:** There is no charges for the stopped jobs. It will be billed on basis on **steaming units in Cloud** and **jobs/devices in Edge**.

**Detailed explanation:**

As a cloud service, Stream Analytics is optimized for cost. There are no upfront costs involved - you only pay for the streaming units you consume, and the amount of data processed. There is no commitment or cluster provisioning required, and you can scale the job up or down based on your business needs.

While creating stream Analytics Job, if you created a Stream Analytics job with **streaming units = 1**, it will be billed **$0.11/hour**.

[image]

**Pricing:**

**Azure Stream Analytics on Cloud:** If you created a Stream Analytics job with streaming units with N, it will be billed $0.11 * N/hour.

**Azure Stream Analytics on Edge:** Azure Stream Analytics on IoT Edge is priced by the number of jobs that have been deployed on a device. For instance, if you have two devices and the first device has one job whereas the second device has two jobs your monthly charge will be **(1 job)*(1 device)*($1/job/device)+(2 jobs)*(1 device)*($1/job/device) = $1+$2 = $3 per month**.

Hope this helps. If you have any further query do let us know.